# Date Manipulation as text field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access 2010 as a front-end to a database on SQL Server 2008. I have a date field which is stored as a nvarchar(50). I have the following value in the text field DateHr `12/04/11 16:49:23` , which should translate to `April 11, 2012 4:49 PM` (As is the date and time the record was created.).

I cannot change the datatype of the field to DateTime as it messes up the dates even more (`Ex. 12/4/2011 4:49:23 PM`). I cannot change the way the record is entered.

I need to display this field in the format "mm/dd/yy" and be able to do where clause in this format.

I have tried the following just to see if it displaying correctly but dtDate is displaying `11/12/04`:

`Select (Format(CDate([DateHr]),"yy/mm/dd")) as dtDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SQL Server view to expand the year component of the date text to 4 digits.  Then `SELECT CDate([DateHr]) AS dtDate FROM YourView` should work from the Access side.  However it might be better still to have the view cast the date text to an actual date type ... then you could use it directly from Access without the need for `CDate()`.

Comment: Can I create a new computed column on SQL Server side and use that is the date in a more readable format?

Comment: In a computed column in the table?  I haven't done that.  You can do it with a view.

Comment: Edited a bit, but worked. `Select CDate(Format(CDate("20" & [DateHr]),"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

Comment: In that case I wonder if you still need `Format()`.  Does this work? `Select CDate("20" & [DateHr])`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to carry out the conversion in access then you can try either of these:

```
Select Mid([DateHr],4,2) & "/" & Mid([DateHr],1,2) & "/" & Mid([DateHr],7,2) as dtDate
```

This I think will give you the date in a string format, otherwise you could try the following to get it in a valid date format:

```
Select Format(DateSerial(Mid([DateHr],7,2),Mid([DateHr],4,2),Mid([DateHr],1,2)),"MM/DD/YYYY") as dtDate
```

Comment: Can I query between a range of dates?

Comment: @Rick Yes, you could use that second "Format" example i've given in a where clause and use the standard Between #Date1# And #Date2# after it